# Knockout Foreach Duplicates when changing order

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

here's pseudocode of my HTML

```
foreach: thing
 ifnot: thing.disabled
  <div>Enabled</div>
  put enabled thing.stuff here
  //this is a ko.observable(bool), and moves "this"thing to the other div
  click: thing.toggleDisabled()


foreach: thing
 if: thing.disabled
  <div>Disabled</div>
  put disabled thing.stuff here
  //this is a ko.observable(bool), and moves "this"thing to the other div
  click: thing.toggleDisabled()
```

I have a large nested object of objects coming from our API. I ko foreach over the object two times. The first time, I check to see if a property is false. If so, it is enabled. Put it in the top div. If it is true, the object is disabled, put it in the bottom div.

```
            <!--ko foreach: {data: $root.list.listObj.rows, as: 'row'}-->
            <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
            <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p data-bind="text: row.rule"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span data-bind="click: function(){$root.list.enableCriteria(row)}">Disable</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ko-->
            <!--/ko-->

  self.enableCriteria = function (row) {

       row.disabled(!row.disabled());
    };
```

The function you see there simply toggles the value of the "disabled" property. All of this works fine.

Here's the issue: My UI uses a click and drag "sortable" style feature to rearrange the order of these elements by allowing the user to click and drag. Knockout creates the element the "foreach" is bound to *for each object* being iterated over. When one element is dragged above or below the other element, it is added between the "foreach element" for ONE object, but now that has TWO objects. When the value is toggled from true to false, since there are now TWO objects within one "foreach element" the top element stays, while a copy of it is moved down to the other div, essentially duplicating it.

Here's a portion of the **rendered** html from the chrome browser tools.

```
<!--ko foreach: {data: $root.list.listObj.rows, as: 'row'}-->
            <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
            <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p data-bind="text: row.rule">Phone:</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span data-bind="click: $root.list.enableCriteria(row)">Disable</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ko-->

            <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
            <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p data-bind="text: row.rule"> Address:</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span data-bind="click: $root.list.enableCriteria(row)">Disable</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ko-->
```

here's what it looks like after one of the .col-md-6 divs have been moved (notice one of the looping comments has no content, and the other has both elements within it):

```
<!--ko foreach: {data: $root.list.listObj.rows, as: 'row'}-->
            <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
            <!--/ko-->

            <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
            <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p data-bind="text: row.rule"> Address:</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span data-bind="click: $root.list.enableCriteria(row)">Disable</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p data-bind="text: row.rule">Phone:</p>
                </div>

            <!--/ko-->
```

Phone has now been moved below Address, but it is within the other  portion. When I toggle the value now, it will create a NEW element in the other "Disabled" or"Enabled" div.

**QUESTION**: Is there any way to make the looping elements/components/whatevers associated with the div within that element for use with my sortable? Are there work arounds for observables to make this work better? What is the solution to this?

Using element for the foreach instead of comment breaks my sortable. any help?

Comment: Have you considered making two observable arrays (one for the enabled items and the other for disabled items)? Then you can just use the `foreach` binding on each observable array and have the `Disable` click event move that item from one observable array to the other.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to give that a shot tomorrow. I am very burned out trying to get this to work :C Thanks for the suggestion. 

I've found, since working with KO, that you often are forced to not use built in KO functionality. You'll struggle for hours, and wind up having to revert to some other tech for the more complex problems... For simple objects and websites, it's a cinch, but I don't think I'll ever use it on another enterprise project because of little bugs like this.

Answer (score 0):

After spending until 1AM working on this (another 4 hours after I posted this), and 2 hours this morning, I came up with a nifty work around.

In KO if you use a commented if or ifnot statement, the observable is only evaluated when it is within the if or ifnot comment, and even then it seems, only within the if or ifnot comment to which it belongs. The loop was going fine, but putting the if statement on a div element means that the div is what is being shuffled and rearranged, so there are never any duplicates.

Takeaway, if you need to do any sort of dom shuffling or rearranging, setting your if and ifnot's to an actual element instead of the comment syntax.

Thanks for the suggestions!